# Japanese grammar structure order

Tags: grammar

Everything I have known about Japanese grammar structure till now is S-O-V. Japanese is S-O-V language. But what's about adj? Adverb?... Something like that. Of couse that I did some research about this. But all I found is this:

> Sentence Topic, Time, Location, Subject, Indirect Object, Direct
>   Object, Verb. [[Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar)]

But I understand nothing at all. I mean it isn't answer my question: the order of adj, adverb... Is it standing before noun or after, what happen if I got 2 adj...
Do you guys know it? Please teach me about it. It terribly confuses me.

And thank you for reading my... query?

Comment: You might be interested in this question as well: [Sentence structure/element order](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6095)

Comment: Well, I had read it before I created this thread. But I still confuse because it hard to understand and not essential enough. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives (and relative clauses for that matter) are always *before* the noun they modify. I don't know if there are rules for the ordering of adjective groups. Maybe [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar) can tell you more.

As for the `I understand nothing at all` part:

- Wikipedia can help you on "sentence topic";
- "time" refers to time expressions such as "three hours ago", "yesterday", "in a week" etc.;
- "location" means an expression indicating the place where an action takes place, such as "here", "in a church", "near the riverbank", "underneath a tree" etc.;
- "Subject" is the subject, which is roughly the doer of the action, but there are exceptions, most notably the verb `aru` (~to have), where the subject is the topic and what is possesed is the subject; `aru` is lit. to exist, so `As for (possessor), (possessed thing) exists` is the idea behind it, reminding me of the Latin use of the dative in this case;
- "Indirect object" is a second object some verbs have, e.g. "give", where it is the person you give something; and "direct object" is the "object" in SOV.
- "Verb" is the sentence's verb.

I honestly didn't know place expressions were confined to before the subject; and time expressions as well. I'm rather inclined to think that this is flexible, and the only real rule is that the verb ends the sentence - for which, unfortunately, you can find exceptions in songs.

Also, I don't know whether to include complements of motion (from somewhere, to swhr., through swhr.) in "location" or not.

I will take look in the cited source and see what it says. Or maybe I'll just wait for comments here.

**Update:** the cited reference states that:

> Japanese is flexible in terms of word-order due to use of particles. Sentences, however, generally have the following structure:
>
> > Sentence Topic, Time, Location, Subject, Indirect Object, Direct Object, Verb.

Also, it does not appear (most incredibly in my opinion) to have anything about the adjective-noun ordering in a location you'd expect to find it in. I might consider reporting this to the wikibooks community. Somebody definitely should.

Comment: It is indeed unbelievable that in a book on Japanese grammar such as the cited source there is nothing easily findable on this topic. It should be reported to Wikibooks.

Comment: Yes, I also know Japanese structure is flexible. But how flexible can it be? For example:
私は Tú です。
And:
Tú は私です。
Is the same? Is that flexible?

I'm sorry if my above question isn't clearly enough.

Comment: No. `私は Tú です` would translate to `I am Tú`, whereas `Tú は私です` would be `Tú is me`, for all I know. But then you put the `は` on two different things in the two sentences, so you can't expect them to be the same. In general these phrases do not allow any permutation, for all I know, since the `…です` part cannot be split, and `は` cannot be placed before the topic they mark.