# Where do adjectives fit in the sentence structure?

Tags: grammar

So I watched this video, and found it very helpful.

I researched a bit more and cleared up why they were saying で was to be used as a particle after a place, instead of に like I'd thought, which was because both can be used, but they are used in different contexts.

Throughout this little research I did, I had a hard time understanding where adjectives were supposed to fit still.

Was there something really obvious I missed, and could you help explain to me where adjectives should go?

I've never learned another language before so I'm trying multiple approaches. I apologize if this is a ridiculous question but if I could get some help I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

(Video: [Uki Uki Japanese Lesson 17 - Basic Sentence Structure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6cb17mZ0dw&list=WL&index=57&t=347s))

Edit: I've also just taken a look at [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20922/japanese-grammar-structure-order?rq=1) article, and seen that they always go before the noun, and also that the Japanese sentences are flexible, but is there any basic rule of thumb where you should have your adjectives in front of any of the other sentence components?

Comment: Friendly reminder: Include what kind of sentence/language features you want to ask into your question, external resource links should only used for supplementary references.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know. I'll have to look at the rules tomorrow and edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where adjectives should go.
>
> that they always go before the noun, and also that the Japanese sentences are flexible, but is there any basic rule of thumb where you should have your adjectives in front of any of the other sentence components?

Adjectives or adverbs anything modifies something come right before the word it modifies: あかい{red} ぼうし{hat}, わたしの{my} ともだち{friend}, はやく{fast} はしる{run}. **[the 'fast' is meant to be an adverb]**

The video seems not to get into the placement of adjectives, but it has this sentence:

> ちちは　ははのたんじょうびに　えきのちかくで　きれいなバラを　かいました。

Here ははの (Mother's) is **modifier to** たんじょうび (birthday) .
More in detail, [〔はは{mother} + の{of}〕 + たんじょうび{birthday}] + に{on}

Likewise, [〔えき{station} + の{of}〕 +  ちかく {near}] + で{at}

きれいな{beautiful} + バラ{roses} + を{object marker} + かいました{bought}.

It might be hard to see what I'm doing here, but I hope it can help you in some way.

Comment: I think in your はやく はしる example you should change 'fast' to 'quickly' to avoid confusing the OP. 'fast run' sounds like an adjective modifying a noun rather than an adverb modifying a verb.

Comment: I hope it works this way. :)