# Can the direct object (with を) appear before the instrumental (with で)?

Tags: particles, syntax

I apologize if this question is too basic, but I was doing some beginner exercises on an app (no, not *that* app), and it marked this as incorrect:

> あのアメリカ人はラーメンをフオークで食べていますね。

The correct order, it insisted, should be:

> あのアメリカ人はフオークでラーメンを食べていますね。

However, on the linked video found on [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50389/where-do-adjectives-fit-in-the-sentence-structure), both should *technically* be correct, right? Is the app wrong to mark it incorrect, or am I misunderstanding the flexibility of Japanese sentence structure?

If it's not technically incorrect, what would the first order imply or indicate that the second, which I gather is the standard order, wouldn't?

Comment: Both orders are correct. There can be small difference in emphasis. See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19433/, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/91410/

Comment: @Arfrever Thanks! I had searched for this topic, but I guess I didn't use the right search terms. I appreciate the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are perfectly correct and natural as far as the word order goes. In this case, neither is more natural than the other.

But let me point out these:

- It's フォーク (fork), not フオーク (fu'ohk).
- ね is for light confirmation. If this sentence is more like "Hey, look at that American!", you should say this instead:

  > あのアメリカ人はフォークでラーメンを食べています**よ**。

Comment: Thanks! The first was a typo (I'm actually not sure how to type ォ on Linux yet, but I will try to figure it out). The second is great to know, but unfortunately, I had to work with what the app had suggested. But your correction doesn't inspire confidence in the app now!

Comment: @cmw In software which I use, *x* + ... creates small characters (e.g. *xo* for ぉ/ォ, *xtu* for っ/ッ).

Comment: @Arfrever ありがとうございます！

Comment: @cmw To input ォ by itself, you can use `xo`, but you can just use `fo` to input フォ. The small-o is typically used with フ, so it's worth remembering (and shouldn't be hard to remember).